# VSCode Not showing 121 further errors and warnings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know that VS Code limits error warnings to 250, and that after this it displays the Not showing ### further errors and warning message.

But I cannot get to any of them.  It says there are 121, so less than the max limit, but all of them are wrapped in 1 Problem with no descriptions of anything in detail.

Surely this is not how it is supposed to be.

Is there a setting I can change that will display my messages?

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a counting/maximum error/warnings issue.  Same file, now with 5 errors is showing all the errors as normal.  How can I get it to show me the error messages up to this limit, because the current message telling me there are errors, but not telling me what they are is about as useless as it gets.